# How to convert memcpy to memcpy_s?

Tags: c, memory, memcpy

I am just a beginner in C. I have written a code in C with a lot of memcpy functions. I want to convert the memcpy statements to memcpy_s.. I don't quite get the syntax to do this.

This is my code snippet:

```
signed char buffer[MAX]; 
unsigned char len; 
const char *scenario = ConvertMap[identity]; 
len = strlen(scenario); 
memcpy((void*)&buffer[0],scenario,len);
```

How do I convert the last line to memcpy_s? Is it like:

`memcpy_s((void*)&buffer[0], sizeof(buffer), scenario, len)` ?

Comment: Is this C or C++? In the latter there may be other techniques.

Comment: This is C programming

Comment: What are `trace_buf` and `EventName`? What is the problem with your version of `memcpy_s`? Is there a compilation error message, or crash, or wrong behaviour? You haven't clearly explained what the actual problem is.

Comment: Are you asking SO to code that "simple" func fo ryou?? If so it is off topic. Show us your efforts and we will help you on problems.

Comment: Hi, edited the memcpy_s function which I have writen (probably wrong?). Just that I am unaware of the memcpy_s function. I have given the syntax which I have written above. If someone could confirm or correct the memcpy_s syntax which I have written, would be great

Comment: Yes, it is my implementation. So it that correct? From your words, I think it is fine?

Comment: I'm not getting you. Do you wantonly to cnage calls from `memcpy` to `memcpy_s`? If so I have no idea if `sizeof(trace_buf)` is the correct size you have to pass to `memcpy_s`. As far As I can Understand it should be `memcpy_s((void*)&buffer[0], MAX, scenario, len)` or `memcpy_s((void*)&buffer[0], sizeof(buffer), scenario, len)`

Comment: Don't cast to `void *`

Comment: Did you try to run that code before asking? The way your question is formulated makes it look like you're asking before you've tried it.

Comment: @sokkyoku trial and error is not a good way to code in C

Comment: @M.M I don't see why not. It's easy to read the man, make a minimal program that uses the function to check that you understand it properly and then use it once you've got it working. Asking others if X will work when trying X is trivial is not a good use of SO.

Comment: @M.M could you please let me know why the (void*) casting is removed?

Comment: @cids yes, it's a good principle to avoid casts because some compilers will suppress an important error message if you use a cast.  Also it is easier to read the code without clutter.

Comment: Or you might want to consider using `strlcpy (buffer, scenario, sizeof buffer);`  without `strlen`

Answer (score 5):

The code could be:

```
memcpy_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), scenario, len)
```

although maybe you would want to use `len+1` if you intend to copy a null-terminated string. (But in that case, use `strcpy_s`).

Also you should allow for the error case:  either design the rest of your code to behave properly if the memcpy failed (buffer will be nulled out), or check the return value and take action on failure.

Comment: or `strncpy_s`?